# Unable to get matching SHA1 digest from bouncycastle and openssl dgst

Tags: java, scala, shell, bouncycastle, sha

Am i going crazy? Here's my scala code with `"org.bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk15on" % "1.59"`

```
import java.util.Base64
import java.security.MessageDigest
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
import java.security.Security
import java.nio.charset.Charset

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider)
val sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1", "BC")
val digest = sha1.digest("foo".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))

Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(digest)
```

this produces, for `foo` input `C+7Hteo/D9vJXQ3UfzxbwnXaijM=`

Openssl:

```
openssl dgst -binary -sha1 <<< "foo" | openssl enc -base64
```

for `foo` input  `8dLS+STphqyG/fezbJS83zK+7BU=`

The same is happening for MD5 and SHA256
Obviously someone is doing something different than the other.. but what?

I verified base64 encoding in isolation between openssl enc -base64 and java.util.Base64, and it seems like there's an extra character(..) in the openssl output, plus java.util.Base64 pads, otherwise it's a match

```
scala> Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString("foo,bar,etc".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
res6: String = Zm9vLGJhcixldGM=

$ openssl enc -base64 <<< "foo,bar,etc"
Zm9vLGJhcixldGMK
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because shell adds a newline to the end of `<<< foo`, so the string that openssl sees is not just "foo", but rather "foo\n".

Try `echo -n foo | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | base64`

Comment: /sigh

thanks, i figured it was the base64 encoding that was doing this, never suspected the shell :-)

Answer (score 0):

i must respond with a redundant answer because i arrived here with the same issue, and my karma is less than 15.  Dima is spot-on

```
echo test|openssl dgst -md4
(stdin)= 36d729ab4ff7260da6fb010ef5747bb3

 echo -n test|openssl dgst -md4
(stdin)= db346d691d7acc4dc2625db19f9e3f52
```

the second result confirms bouncycastle as well. there is at the time of this response an online digest checker with an md4 option, it concurs with the second result also.